# .Nest Fluent Dsl Aggregations

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, fluent

I am using Elasticsearch .Nest.
I need to create a search query that will return fileProperties objects but only of the latest version of each fileProperties.
Each FileId have many versions. So what I need is to do a groupBy FileId and get the whole document object with the Max version for each FileId.
This my class:

```
public class FileProperties
{

    public string FileName { get; set; }       
    public string FileId { get; set; }       
    public long? Version { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> DynamicProperties { get; set; }       
}
```

and my code:

```
 var searchResponse = client.Search<FileProperties>(s => s.AllIndices().Size(100)
        .Query(q =>
        q.Match(m => m
       .Field(f => f.FileName)
       .Query(fileId))
        && q.Match(m => m
       .Field(f => f.Version)
       .Query(version))).Aggregations(fstAgg => fstAgg
.Terms("file", f => f
  .Field(z => z.FileId.Suffix("keyword"))
   .ExecutionHint(TermsAggregationExecutionHint.GlobalOrdinals)
    .Aggregations(sums => sums
      .Max("version", son => son
      .Field(f4 => f4.Version )
    )
  )
) ) );
```

But the results only show the key and the max value for that key.
what I want is the full document object if that is possible...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want the source docs listed I the buckets?

Comment: @ sramalingam24 yes

Comment: I know top_hits aggregation can return source fields in the buckets, so you may try adding that in there in the end and you can specify select fields to return using "_source":[]